# Custodian Badge Progress bug - awarded, but it still says I have to review 1 item

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges, review, late-answers

It says that I have to review one more item to get Custodian badge for Late Answers, but I already got one **10 days ago**.

[image]
[image]

Here's how it should look like (screenshot from Close Votes):

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep, off by one - fixed and will be deployed shortly.